# fatal error: asm/rwonce.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

*Sorry, I'm not very familiar with C and kernel programming, just need to write some bindings around syscalls.*

I'm trying to compile a program to call Linux syscall directly. I've installed linux headers to `/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/`. When I'm compiling it using gcc, the file `asm/rwonce.h` could not be found. I created a minimal reproducible example:

```c
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm compiling it using `gcc -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include -o test_program test_program.c`. The error is:

```
In file included from /usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include/linux/export.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include/linux/linkage.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/aio_abi.h:31,
                 from /usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include/linux/syscalls.h:79,
                 from test_program.c:1:
/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include/linux/compiler.h:246:10: fatal error: asm/rwonce.h: No such file or directory
  246 | #include <asm/rwonce.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have double checked the file `/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include/linux/syscalls.h` exists. gcc works fine with this include:

```
$ gcc -E -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include - < /dev/null
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

I tried to add manually `/usr/include` but it didn't help: `gcc -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include -I/usr/include -o test_program test_program.c`

I found that `asm/rwonce.h` is located at `/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/arch/x86/include/generated/asm/rwonce.h`, but adding it as `gcc -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/src/kernel-headers-6.5.4_1/arch/x86/include/generated -o test_program test_program.c` caused much more problems (first it can't find `asm/linkage.h` header, then it can't match some  function signatures).

I'm using Void linux kernel headers package. My current kernel is `6.5.4_1`, gcc version is `gcc (GCC) 12.2.0`.

How to solve this include issue and compile program with kernel headers correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually issue a syscall use the [`syscall`](https://manned.org/syscall.2) library function from `unistd.h` (you may need to add `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE` at the very top of your source code), do not include kernel headers directly e.g. with `-I`. What you need should already be available without additional compiler flags. Userspace kernel headers are usually installed along with libc development headers. You may have a libc version that is too old.

RE: "I want to call a new cachestat syscall" - if you have a 6.5 kernel for which userspace headers were correctly installed, you should be able to find the definitions for `struct cachestat` and `struct cachestat_range` in `sys/mman.h` or `linux/mman.h`.

In any case, these structures are pretty simple. You can just re-define them in your source code if other options don't work:

```c
struct cachestat_range {
    uint64_t off;
    uint64_t len;
};

struct cachestat {
    uint64_t nr_cache;
    uint64_t nr_dirty;
    uint64_t nr_writeback;
    uint64_t nr_evicted;
    uint64_t nr_recently_evicted;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But how I can use structures and defines from linux headers to perform syscall? I want to call a new `cachestat` syscall from 6.5 https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.5-MM-cachestat , so I need to get `struct cachestat_range` , `struct cachestat` and `__NR_cachestat`

Comment: Ah, so this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) :')

Comment: @Kirill Have you tried upgrading the userspace linux headers package, i.e. the package that installs /usr/include/linux/? (I do not know what the package is called in Void Linux, but on Debian it is `linux-libc-dev`.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when trying to compile a USB WiFi adapter driver. In my case instead of the directory name being `asm` it was `asm-generic`.

Here is a link to my posted solution https://askubuntu.com/a/1495186/326349 There is another posted solution which says the files were moved from `asm` to `asm-generic`.

The error displayed in my case was:

```
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$ make
make ARCH=riscv64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build M=/home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-9) 12.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Debian 12.2.0-10) 12.2.0
  CC [M]  /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/build_bug.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/container_of.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/include/basic_types.h:76,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/include/drv_types.h:26,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/compiler.h:254:10: fatal error: asm/rwonce.h: No such file or directory
  254 | #include <asm/rwonce.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:254: /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/Makefile:1876: /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build'
make: *** [Makefile:2410: modules] Error 2
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$
```

And the solution I used was to create a symbolic link `./asm` to the existing directory `./asm-generic`.

```
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include$ ls
acpi         crypto       keys   linux     memory  pcmcia  rv    sound   uapi  video
asm-generic  drm          kunit  math-emu  misc    ras     scsi  target  ufs   xen
clocksource  dt-bindings  kvm    media     net     rdma    soc   trace   vdso
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include$ sudo ln -s ./asm-generic ./asm
```